# Specify a Region for the pcl::PointCloud Data and Get the Available Points

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am searching for a method or algorithm for the pcl::PointCloud object which accepts a rectangular, or even circular, region based on pixel coordinates and in turn return all the available points in that region.

For example:

1. inputs: 100px < w < 120px, 240px < h < 360px,
2. output: points in XYZ

Answer (score 0):

For pixel-level slicing just crop the image before generating the point cloud. For example in OpenCV:

```
cv::Rect myROI(100, 240, 20, 120); 
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);
```

In case you want to slice the data in Euclidean coordinates, you can use a [PassThrough](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_pass_through.html) filter:

```
pcl::PassThrough<PointType> ptfilter (true); // Initializing with true will allow us to extract the removed indices
ptfilter.setInputCloud (cloud_in);
ptfilter.setFilterFieldName ("x");
ptfilter.setFilterLimits (0.0, 1000.0);
ptfilter.filter (*indices_x);
```

In the case of a spherical region around your origin, use the [radiusSearch](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1search_1_1_kd_tree.html#a465893c20b7cd452329fcd775873a7bf) method from the Kdtree object and query which points are located within a radius around your origin.

Comment: What is the quantity for ptfilter.setFilterLimits (0.0, 1000.0)?

Comment: In this example points with x values of 0 to 1000 meters will be kept

Comment: I want to specify the pixels not meter!

Comment: In that case just crop the image before generating the point cloud. For example in OpenCV:


`cv::Rect myROI(100, 240, 20, 120);
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);`